Implementing gradual territory capture in a two-dimensional strategy game in Godot 4
I'm developing a 2D game in Godot 4 and I want to implement a territory conquest mechanic similar to what you see in games like Age of History. The idea is for the player to gradually “paint” enemy territory with their own color as they conquer it.  The polygons added to the map are now sections of the countries themselves, and collisionpolygon2d was designed to allow the player to select any country. I'd also like to avoid using a province based system.
I've seen this question before but didn't see an answer, I'm interested in exactly the same thing, I'd like to at least get an idea of how to do this gradual conquest, what functionality to use for this ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
